# Regular expressions in cucumber steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, cucumber, webrat

Cucumber generates out some neat webrat regex steps. I encountered a problem when I tried the this.

**In feature:**

```
And I fill in "Telephone (Home)" with "61234567"
```

**In webrat steps:**

```
When /^I fill in "([^\"]*)" with "([^\"]*)"$/ do |field, value|
  fill_in(field, :with => value) 
end
```

**The error encountered:**

```
Could not find field: "Telephone (Home)" (Webrat::NotFoundError)
```

It seems that the parenthesis between "Home" is giving problem. How do I tweak the regex to account for parenthesis?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that the regex wasn't the problem as the "**field**" instance variable did yield "Telephone (Home)". The real problem was the way webrat's "**fill_in**" method parses the field variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This encountered me too with the field "(log out)"...

You could call for the id field?

```
fill_in("user_telephone_home", :with => data)
```

Comment: Yup I ended up using field's id although it sticks out like a sore thumb in my cucumber feature definitions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to capture *"Telephone"* try this:

```
/^I fill in "(\w+).*?" with "([^\"]*)"$/
```

If it's *"Home"* you're after try this:

```
/^I fill in "(?:.*?\()?(.+?)\)?" with "([^\"]*)"$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with matching labels to fields in webrat, and I came up with this code snippet which loosens the regexp used to match a label to a field.  Maybe it will help you out.

I have this in my `features/support/env.rb`

```
module Webrat
  module Locators
    class FieldLabeledLocator < Locator
      def matching_label_elements_with_numbering
        label_elements.select do |label_element|
          text(label_element) =~ /^.*#{Regexp.escape(@value.to_s)}.*$/i
        end
      end
      alias_method_chain :matching_label_elements, :numbering
    end
  end
end
```

http://gist.github.com/169215